# A mosfet switch for PWM signal

Tags: mosfet, pwm

I was wondering if my circuit will work.

[image: Circuit diagram]

The 5V signal is coming from a microcontroller, based on a condition. If its 1(5V) I want the PWM signal to be received by the motor. If its 0, the motor shouldn't get any signal and thus not rotate.

What specs of the mosfet should I look into?

Thanks!

EDIT: I think I am using the wrong term for "motor", I am sorry, I don't know what else to call it. I will be using it to either drive an ESC or a servo motor.

The signal comes from the PWM output of Erle Brain 2, which has a 25 mA current sink capability at 5V.

P.S. Thanks everyone for your inputs! Really appreciate it! :)

Comment: It all depends on the motor.

Comment: You're using the NMOS as a **source follower** meaning it will drop 2 V (roughly) from the 5 V so the signal to motor will be a 3 V signal. If that's OK for the motor and the NMOS is indeed dropping 2 V and not much more, it can work.

Comment: What's Your motor? Has it got built-in regulator?

Comment: PWM seems to come from uC (as written in schematic). Signal comes from MCU (as stated in description). I suspect uC and MCU are actually the same component. If it is the case, there is obviously a simpler way, using software.

Comment: A 'motor' with +12V, signal input, and Ground connections? Please tell what us you _really_ want to drive. An ESC? A brushless fan with PWM speed control input?

Comment: I will be driving an ESC.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if you already know this, but the configuration for your Nchan is a source follower, which is typically used as a current buffer.  More plainly, a circuit which will produce the same signal (minus VGS) on the source that is on the gate, but with more current, which limited by what the Nchan can supply (drain to source) and also limited by the capability of the power supply, which would normally be coupled to the drain.  In this case
you substituted a PWM signal for the power supply.

What you are doing is using an Nchan as a gate, to "gate" an on/off signal from a micro-controller to pass a PWM signal to a motor.

First of all, this circuit will work, however this depends on the input current requirement of the motor at the PWM input, and also, what kind of
Nchan you use.  There are basically two types of Nchan's, which are lower
power, and higher power.  I would suggest you NOT use a higher power Nchan
because the Vgs turn on voltage is usually in the neighborhood of 2VDC.
Using something like a 2N7000 would work (Vgs turn on = 0.7VDC), however it 
can only supply a maximum of 200mA from drain to source.  If the PWM input 
of your motor requires more than that, this approach will not work.

I would like to suggest you use a logic gate instead of an Nchan.
Specifically I suggest using an AND gate.  Put your PWM signal into one
input of the AND gate, and on/off signal from the mirco-controller to the
other input of the AND gate.  The motor's PWM signal is essentially a digital
input (1 or 0).  It's just the duration between the 1 and 0 change (duty 
cycle).

If you choose this approach, please be cautious about choosing an AND gate
that can supply a sufficient amount of current to the motor's PWM input.

Lastly, if you stick with using an Nchan, I would be cautious about swapping 
the PWM and on/off signals to the Nchan.  If you choose to do that, please 
make sure your micro-controller's output can supply enough current to the 
motor's PWM input.  Most micro-controllers (Arduino) supply very low output
currents.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need around 25 mA of PWM input, so will AND gate work for me?

Comment: @user3764464 25mA at what voltage? Please tell us more about this 'motor' which needs a 25mA PWM signal.

Comment: The current requirement (25mA) is high for a logic gate.  In this case I would suggest using a buffer between the logic gate and the motor's PWM input.  I would use a comparator, with the output of the AND gate going to the (+) side of the comparator, and setting the (-) side of the comparator to a reference voltage that is around Vdd/2.  You will need to choose a comparator that can supply 25mA easily, and have the voltage range necessary (as pointed out by Bruce).

Comment: I forgot to mention that you could build your own AND gate with discrete FETs.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, but I would switch on/off and PWM signals other way. So PWM is on gate and on/off on the drain.

Regarding the mosfet, looks like that line do not have high current consumption? If that is the case, than any N-channel mosfet with threshold gate voltage low enough (<= 2V) would do the job.

Comment: I would not do that with just one MOSFET, on account of that inverting the PWM signal and in the very likely case of RC-Servo type PWM the motor suddenly doing incredibly weird stuff.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how motors work.  They don't have a control input like that.

A motor with a specific controller could be lumped into a box and have three terminals, but then you no longer have a "motor".  In that case, it depends what the specs of the control input are.  If it's a ordinary digital input, then you don't need a transistor between the microcontroller and the motor controller at all.  Otherwise, what you need in between depends on what exactly the controller input requires.

In any case, using a FET in the way you show is iffy at best.  There will be some voltage drop from the gate to the source.  We can't tell without specs whether the result can still be reliably detected as a logic high by the controller.

It seems what you really want is a AND function.  This can be done by a AND gate, but much better would be to perform it as part of the programmable logic in the micro.  Shut down the PWM output in the micro when you want the motor off.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, it would be good to explain what exactly you think is wrong.  I re-read this, and still don't see anything wrong.

Comment: It might be better to say at the start "you may be referring to a motor with an inbuilt controller" which could very well be the case. Starting off by saying "thats not how motors work" is sort of a confusing way to put it. A motor with a built in controller is very common, and referring to the whole thing as a motor is not an unusual thing to do.